# Can't create RESTful Web Service with maven on IntelliJ Idea 2017.3.4

Tags: java, rest, maven, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I need to create a `RESTful` Web Service with `JavaEE` on `IntellijIdea` using maven for librairies. I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/preparing-for-rest-development.html?keymap=primary_default_for_gnome) to help me create  this project but I have one problem:

When I arrive at the fourth step: "Enabling REST support when creating a project", I can't select the option : "Set up library later" to help in  setting up maven after.

[image: Screen of intellij]

As you can see, I don't have the selection avaible.

For more details, I have `IntelliJ` IDEA Version 2017.3.4 and I work on debian 8.

Does anyone have a solution for my particular problem ?

Comment: Why can you not tell IntelliJ the library now?  I assume this means "Here is how I plan to generate the REST service" - Jersey or some other mechanism.

Comment: i would like to manage my librairies with maven so i think if i set a librairie now, i can't after

Comment: Yes you can. You must have some idea now of what you’d like to use. Set it now; add it to Maven. If you change your mind, synch the two up again. I doubt that it’ll be very dynamic. Do it and move on.

Comment: I don't have choice. Thanks for helping

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post is old, but answer could be useful to the community anyway.

I've found a solution: looks like the problem is because it's selected  `Java EE 8`, and there aren't libraries available yet.

If you start a new project wizard, then you select `Java EE 7`, and then you select `RESTful Web Service` a "dowload" button will appear, and you can then proceed to next step
[image]